# Adding ads in android apps

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am using google play services library for adding ads in my android application. My android platform is 4.3. But it is showing that `could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method`.

Comment: Did you include the lib

Comment: android studio? if so, show gradle

Comment: Sorry, i am using eclipse IDE only

Comment: and the android platform is 4.3

Comment: These days I am using Android Studio with kotlin. And the problem was solved

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this simple steps:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: thank you Lennon, i don't know whether it works with android studio, anyway i am using eclipse. and the platform is 4.3. i think there is no compile errors, but when it launched, the sample project 'admob' also not working.

Comment: Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.iqbaltld.bustiming.ActMain.onCreate

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #177: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.

Comment: Follow this steps: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/eclipse

Comment: Lennon, Thanks again.
I will check it

Comment: Nop, i can't even see the google play services option inside sdk manager

Comment: The google play is inside `Extras`. So you can see Extras\Google Play services and install it

Comment: i have manually downloaded Google play libraries and now Its ok, but still the error appears "Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView', referenced from method com.......ActMain.onCreate

Comment: Did you add correctly the following dependencies into your `build.gradle`?
`dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    }`

Comment: Thank you all, all is well after I started with Android studio